# How can I delete data from IFileListEntry?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying to delete datas from **IFileListEntry**, however I couldn't find out how to do it.
Would you like to look at below code and give me some approaches?. How can I clear or remove all FileListEntry?

```
========== razor code ==========
<BlazorInputFile.InputFile OnChange="FileUpload" />

========== cs code ==========
IFileListEntry[] fileList;
public async Task FileUpload(IFileListEntry[] files)
{
    fileList = files;
    var file = fileList.First();
    if (file != null)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        await file.Data.CopyToAsync(ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot.  `IFileListEntry` is designed to give you access to the files the user selected for upload.  If you don't want to process certain files, just don't, but I guess you are asking a wrong question or doing something wrong.

Comment: @Nick Sorry for my bad English. Your answer is properly. Really thank you for answering my stupid questions well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. IFileListEntry is designed to give you access to the files the user selected for upload. If you don't want to process certain files, just don't.